# Функция неопределённого местоимения в предложении

Tags: синтаксис

Возьмите кто-нибудь трубку.

Нашла в творческой работе шестиклассницы такое вот предложение. Стало интересно: кто-нибудь — это подлежащее? Или обращение? Конструкция, конечно,  разговорного стиля, но всё-таки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такие примеры рассматриваются двояко, в зависимости от паузы. Вот что говорится в Корпусной грамматике:

> Помимо личного местоимения ты / вы, подлежащее в императивных предложениях в редких случаях может быть выражено иными способами.
>   Иногда подлежащее выражено неопределенным местоимением ***кто-нибудь или целой предикацией с местоимением кто (типа кто может, кто хочет):***
>   Сергей Николаич сгреб его спереди за руки и сильно сдавил. – Ну-ка, кто-нибудь помогите! – позвал он. [В. Шукшин. Штрихи к портрету (1973)]
>   ...

- Помогите кто может! к врачу обратиться не могу - нет страховки...
  [Красота, здоровье, отдых: Медицина и здоровье (форум) (2005)]

Такие случаи часто интерпретируются пишущими как обращение ***(местоимение выделяется запятыми):***

- > – Кто-нибудь, пригласите, пожалуйста, директора, – попросил один из них, видимо, главный, показывая кассиру удостоверение. [А. Житков.
  >   Супермаркет (2000)]

В Корпусе есть также несколько примеров, когда подлежащее выражено отрицательным местоимением ***никто, местоимениями все и те:***
>

- Но оказалось, что прав был также и Шенопин. Он, когда ему говорили,
  он про тюрьму отвечал так: – Ничего, – отвечал он, – никто не
  волнуйтесь. У Шенопина есть небольшой секрет, который избавит его от
  этой неприятной процедуры. [Е. Попов. Влечение к родным деревьям
  (1970-2000)]
- С армян перекинулась на русских. Неверные должны освободить
  мусульманскую землю. Азербайджан – для азербайджанцев. Все, кто
  другие, – езжайте к себе. И даже в школу занесло эту
  националистическую заразу. [В. Токарева. Своя правда (2002)]
- Уйдите, – молила я, прижимая к себе Хучика, – все убирайтесь вон! [Д.
  Донцова. Уха из золотой рыбки (2004)]

  > Те, кто желает поспорить, пишите на мейл. [«Хулиган» (2004)] Местоимения кто-нибудь, все и никто в этих конструкциях можно считать
  >   не подлежащими, а плавающими определителями при нулевом подлежащем,
  >   так как они могут появляться в позиции при ненулевом подлежащем 2-го
  >   лица (М. Холодилова, в устном общении):
  >   Лучше вы кто-нибудь сходите. [Б. Минаев. Детство Левы (2001)]
  >   Эдди, включай проигрыватель, ты, Лулу, приглуши свет, а вы все кончайте болтать. [«Вокруг света» (2004)]

[3.2 Выраженность подлежащего](http://rusgram.ru/%D0%98%D0%BC%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2#32)

Answer (score 0):

Возьми ты трубку. Возьмите вы трубку. Возьмите кто-нибудь трубку.

Получается, что да, подлежащее.

Comment: Сказуемое ВОЗЬМИТЕ предполагает в качестве подлежащего местоимение ВЫ. А у нас КТО-НИБУДЬ. Оно заменяет ВЫ?

Comment: А если местоимение заменить существительным. оно тут же превратится в обращение: возьмите, люди, трубку.

Comment: Вы же сами сказали, что конструкция разговорного стиля. Если заменить существительным, то да, будет обращение.

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю, что грамматика может быть разная, но она определяет выбор пунктуации. Если не "кто-нибудь" не обособлено, то подлежащее, если обособлено, то обращение.

То есть, это авторский выбор. Аналогия с "ты" и "вы" тут очень близкая, местоимения эти тоже в редких случаях становятся обращениями - в силу стилистических особенностей речи персонажа.

Но тут есть одна неприятность. "Кто-нибудь" здесь требует глагола во множественном числе (*"кто-нибудь возьми"* - не получается). А само по себе "кто-нибудь" местоимение единственного числа (*"если кто-нибудь возьмет"*, никак не "возьмут"). Это сильно подрывает веру в подлежащее, и **что** это такое, затрудняюсь сказать наверняка.  Обращение совсем не так жестко требует согласования по роду и числу. Нет аналога в русском, а вообще чем-то напоминает даже эргативную конструкцию.

Про ты и вы в роли обращения см., например, тут. 
http://pravopisanie_i_stilistika.academic.ru/102/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F

Answer (score 0):

**Возьмите кто-нибудь трубку.**

Это нестандартная форма повелительного наклонения со значением "пусть кто-нибудь возьмет".

Как известно, повелительное наклонение имеет тенденцию  выражаться различными способами (например: Пойдем домой. Встать! Быстро встал и вышел!).

Примеры:

― Жалко Марту. Возьмите кто-нибудь Марту к себе домой.  [Вадим Баевский. Центральный поселок // «Звезда», 2008].
«Возьмите кто-нибудь пулемет», ― приказал ротмистр.  [Н. С. Гумилев. Записки кавалериста (1914-1915)]